# Gulp selectively grabbing dependencies

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp

I'm starting a new project in Ionic, and trying to learn how to use Gulp to build my application. I have it working... kind of. I got Gulp to automatically inject the project files, but it's not working with the library dependencies as consistently as I would hope.

I have installed 6 dependencies thus far, but Gulp is only grabbing 2 of them (ng-lodash and angular-messages). Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Help!

gulpfile.js

```
// other code
gulp.task('default', ['sass','index','wiredep']);

gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  gulp.src('./www/index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: './www/lib',
      // devDependencies: true,
      exclude: ['/angular/', 'angular-animate', 'angular-mocks', 'angular-resource', 'angular-sanitize', 'angular-ui-router']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch([
    paths.javascript,
    paths.css
  ], ['index']);
  gulp.watch('./www/index.html', ['wiredep']);
});
// other code
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "robotodraft": "~1.1.0",
    "Ionicons": "ionicons#~2.0.1",
    "ng-lodash": "~0.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "fontawesome#~4.4.0",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.7",
    "ionic-toast": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What about using `"ionic": "1.1.0"` instead of `"ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.1.0"`? That way you don't need to exclude anything. Ionicons are included. `directory` key is not needed because wiredep is smart enough. Can you share your index.html? Can you try with `npm install -g wiredep` and `wiredep --src www/index.html --verbose`?

Comment: Are you sure you have all your bower dependencies installed in ./www/lib folder? It seems like your ionic stuff are not in that folder

Comment: @KateMihalikova Thanks for all your suggestions. I tried the ionic change, and it threw a bunch of errors in my Ionic build. Also, my Ionic build is one of the default templates from their websites, so I'm assuming it's a default from their team. I also tried working with wiredep, and that didn't change anything either. Eventually I just modified my bower.json to override the default installs, and it's worked just fine. I'm not thrilled with the solution, but it will work for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kiong Yep, positive they're in that folder - that was the first thing i checked!

Comment: I'm glad that you managed to make it working somehow :-) The included ionic-bower is the best one in the beginning, but when you use it with wiretap, you need to manually exclude angular packages, which is not needed when using simple ionic, which does not include them by default. It's just the matter of clarity :-)